# Select parent child element when child element matches text using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have html like so:

```
<div class="card">
  <div>Foo</div>
  <a>View Item</a>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div>Bar</div>
  <a>View Item</a>
</div>
```

I want to select the card matching "Bar" and click the "View Item" link. I tried

```
cards = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('card')
for card in cards:
  if card.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Bar'):
     item_anchor = card.find_element_by_partial_link_text('View Item')
     item_anchor.click()
```

However I get the error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Bar"}`

Comment: Bar is simple text in a div, not a link, so `find_element_by_partial_link_text('Bar')` wont work

Comment: even so i don't want to crash if it doesn't find it and would like to know the right way to not do that

Comment: `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Bar')]"):` should work if you want to select <div>Bar</div>

Comment: that worked however if i look up an element that isn't there it completely fails like

browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'not on page')]"):

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

i wonder how to safely catch that

Comment: you can catch the exception, but I would say checking the size is better: `if len(card.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Bar')]")) > 0:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the EC and below xpath.

**Option 1:**

Check if the link exist and then click (you can add the attributes to link in the xpath, if you are looking for any specific link)

```
link =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card' and div[normalize-space(.)='Bar']]/a")))
if (link):
    link.click()
```

Options 2:

Using different xpath and len

```
links =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card']/div[normalize-space(.)='Bar']/following-sibling::a[normalize-space(.)='View Item']")))
if len(links)>0:
    links[0].click()
```

Option 3:

If you are not sure there are any levels present between `B` and `A` you can use the below xpath.

```
links =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[normalize-space(.)='Bar']/ancestor::div[@class='card']//a[normalize-space(.)='View Item']")))
if len(links)>0:
    links[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on `View Item` of `Bar`, you can directly use this xpath :

```
//div[text()='Bar']/following-sibling::a[text()='View Item']
```

However introducing webdriver wait would a great idea for stability as mentioned by **@supputuri**

Answer (score 0):

```
There are two ways to handle this situation based on your UI behavior:

1) If UI is fixed, use this xpath to identify and use click() to click on it.

//*[@class='card']/div[.='Bar']/following-sibling::a

2) If you are taking data from any external sources (like Database or Excel), pass your expected value (like Bar or Foo) as a parameter to the xpath method like below:

Define a class called Element like as below:

public class Element {

    private WebElement element;
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String xpath;

//  Constructor will wrap web element into Object and will allow to use any of the method declared below
    public Element(String xpath) {
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        this.xpath = xpath;
        this.element = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath(this.xpath));
    }

    public void click() {
        this.element.click();
    }
}

Create POM class and write a methods like below:

public class PageObjectClass {

        private Element elementToClick(String value) {
            return new Element("//*[@class='card']/div[.='" + value + "']/following-sibling::a");
        }

        public void clickOnViewItemsLink(String value) {
            this.elementToClick(value).click();
        }
    }

By this way, you can click on any of View Item link just by passing value as a parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by a single line of code by using the correct xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Bar']/following-sibling::a[text()='View Item']")).click();
```